# Dividing CSS Grid Row into Equal Sizes

Tags: css

How can I divide a CSS Grid row with 3 columns into 2 equal sizes? Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/251f04ts/3/

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
}

.one {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.two {
  background-color: blue;
}

.three {
  background-color: purple;
}

.four {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

.five {
  background-color: pink;
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.six {
  background-color: gray;
  grid-column: 2/5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="one">
    one
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    two
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    three
  </div>
  <div class="four">
    four
  </div>
  <div class="five">
    five - this and six should be equal
  </div>
  <div class="six">
    six
  </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: use more column, related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58855236/8620333

Comment: Think you would need to use an amount of columns something divisible by 3 and 2:  (ie 6): https://jsfiddle.net/vt7y0d45/2

Comment: Actually that was not the case. Even odd number of columns can work. See the solution below which uses inner grid.

Comment: That would be a html change too though - the above is a css only solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `.wrapper_the_second` into the row, where you want `.five` and `.six`.

```
.wrapper_the_second{
  grid-column: 1/4;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
}
```

and then

```
.five {
  background-color: pink;
}

.six {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

This should do the work.

---

Jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9e1naudg/